# Function and Array in C++: Unexpected output

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need some help here please.

I just started learning C++ (coming from Python background).

I'm trying to familiarize myself with arrays and functions. Wrote a bunch of functions to do as stated, above each one.

However, the function which is supposed to sum elements in an array and return their sum, seem to be adding 10 to the result, no matter the argument supplied as input. What am I doing wrong please, as I can't seem to find this out. Any help on general layout of my code also would be appreciated.

```
// WORKING WITH ARRAYS AND FUNCTIONS

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

// FUNCTION TO INSTANTIATE ARRAY INT OF LENGTH N.
int* array_creator(int n)
{
    static int ary_of_ten[10];  //declare array
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)   //use loop to fill it up
    {
        ary_of_ten[i] = i+1;
    }
    return ary_of_ten;
}

//FUNCTION TO PRINT ARRAY ELEMENTS
void* array_printer(int arr[], int array_lenght)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array_lenght-1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << arr[array_lenght-1] << endl;
}

//FUNCTION ACCEPTS INT ARRAYS AND RETURNS ARRAY OF SQUARE OF EACH ELEMENT
int* square_array(int *p, int array_length)
{
    const int ary_sz(array_length);
    static int sqd_values[10];
    for (int i=0; i<ary_sz; i++)
    {
        *(sqd_values + i) = *(p+i) * *(p+i);
    }
    return sqd_values;
}

//FUNCTION ACCEPTS INT ARRAYS AND RETURNS SUM OF ITS ELEMENTS
int sum_array(int *arry, int array_length)
{
    int summation;
    for(int i=0; i<array_length; i++)
    {
        summation += *(arry + i);
    }
    return summation;
}

int main()
{
    cout << sum_array(array_creator(10), 3) << endl;
    array_printer(array_creator(10), 10);           //print array of 1-10 elements
    array_printer(square_array(array_creator(10), 10), 10);     //prt arry of sqrd values
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect and why?

Comment: I expect if i call the sum fucntion for an array of 1-10, it should give me an output of 55. so also for the current value there now, summation of first three elements (1, 2, 3) should give 6, not 16.

Comment: `int summation;` <-- you never initialize this variable, so it has an unspecified value when you try to add to it in the loop. Change it to `int summation = 0;`. Change your compiler settings to the maximum warning level; it should have caught this.

Comment: @JJNgr Why do you access the elements of an array in the following way: `*(arry + i)` instead of more readable `arry[i]`? They mean **exactly** the same thing, but 2nd is more readable.

Comment: Your `array_printer` function leads to undefined behavior.  You're supposed to return a `void *`, but you don't return anything.  Your compiler didn't warn you of this?

Comment: @ cdhowie, thank you. Thinking about it now, I actually assumed it would be zero by default..lol. Also, I'll read up how to change the compiler setting. I'm using codeblocks. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ Algirdas, yes that's true. However, I'm trying to familiarize myself with every known way this is done, so if I see it somewhere tomorrow, I'll know what it is. Also, this way, the fact that array name is a pointer is entrenched in me..lol. Thanks.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie, yes it did. However, i thought the whole point of void is to be used for a function that doesn't return any value. If possible, can you assist refactor the code? Thanks.

Comment: @JJNgr Well.. When I said, that those 2 ways of referencing elements in an array are _exactly_ the same, I meant it literally. `arry[i]` does exactly the same operation, under the hood, as you are writing out manually. In addition, your function returns _pointer to_ `void`, not `void`, hence you are expected to return it. If you want your function not to return anything - simply remove the pointer.

Comment: @ Algirdas, I get it now, and thanks for the void pointer thing. I have a better understanding of this now, actually. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

summation shuld be initialized to 0.

int summation=0;

Comment: Thanks Gili L. Fixed.